# Get version from composer.json [Symfony]

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I wonder if there is a way to get the `composer.json` version from a controller with Symfony. My `composer.json` looks like:

```
{
    "name": "myProject",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "myProject description",
    "license": "AGPL-3.0",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        ...
    }
}
```

I can't find any reference to this.

PS: I'm using Symfony 4.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Usually, this is a common JSON file which can be parsed like any other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [PackageVersions](https://packagist.org/packages/ocramius/package-versions) library and its relative [PrettyPackageVersions](https://packagist.org/packages/jean85/pretty-package-versions).

They provide a single class API to get the currently installed version of your Composer dependencies, for example:

```
use PackageVersions\Versions;
use Jean85\PrettyVersions;

// Will output "1.0.0@0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33"
echo Versions::getVersion('myvendor/mypackage');

// Will output "1.0.0"
echo (string) PrettyVersions::getVersion('myvendor/mypackage');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
$filename = $this->getParameter('%app.kernel_dir%') . '/../composer.json';
$composerData = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename), true);

$version = $composerData['version'];
```

The variable should then containv the value `0.0.0` from your example.

This assumes that your controller extends the base Controller to access the `%app.kernel_dir%` parameter. If not, you could just as well use the relative path from your controller or something else to determine the location of the composer.json

Answer (score 3):

Without packages, with Composer you can use `$version = \Composer\InstalledVersions::getPrettyVersion('package/package-name')`

Answer (score 2):

Reffering **Salam** answer, you can also get own project (named `root package` in composer world) version stored in `composer.json` by:

```
$version = \Composer\InstalledVersions::getRootPackage()['version'];
```

or for prettier print:

```
$version = \Composer\InstalledVersions::getRootPackage()['pretty_version'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 6 u have to do the following 3 Steps:

1. Create global Variable in packages/twig.yaml and reference a Service as Value

---

```
twig:
    globals:
        composer_version: '@App\Helper\ComposerVersion'
```

---

2. Create (Service) App\Helper\ComposerVersion:

---

```
namespace App\Helper;

use Composer\InstalledVersions;

class ComposerVersion
{
    public static function getVersion(): string
    {
        return InstalledVersions::getRootPackage()['pretty_version'];
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return self::getVersion();
    }
}
```

---

3. Use in twig Template:

---

```
<div>{{ composer_version }}</div>
```